# How do I loop through a list of dictionaries? | list - error: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I get data from the `community.general.xml` module like this. Next, I need to make a selection with the received data in the same xml file in the loop. But how to address them, I do not know.

I get data like this:

```
{
    "scriptVal": {
        "actions": {
            "xpath": "//subClientProperties[vmContent/children[@displayName=\"test-pc4\"]]/subClientEntity",
            "namespaces": {},
            "state": "present"
        },
        "changed": false,
        "count": 2,
        "matches": [
            {
                "subClientEntity": {
                    "appName": "Virtual Server",
                    "backupsetName": "backupset-test",
                    "clientName": "Name-vcagent",
                    "displayName": "Name-VCAgent",
                    "instanceName": "VC01",
                    "subclientName": "test"
                }
            },
            {
                "subClientEntity": {
                    "appName": "Virtual Server",
                    "backupsetName": "Test01",
                    "clientName": "Name-vcagent",
                    "displayName": "Name-VCAgent",
                    "instanceName": "VC01",
                    "subclientName": "start9pm"
                }
            }
        ],
        "msg": 2,
        "ansible_facts": {
            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python"
        },
        "failed": false
    },
}
```

I need to access each element of the `subClientEntity` dictionaries

Every time my attempt fails:

```
     - debug:
          msg: "{{ item.id }} : {{ item.value] }}"
        loop: "{{ scriptVal.matches.item.subClientEntity | default }}"
```

Result:

```
TASK [debug msg={{ item.id }} : {{ item.value] }}] *****************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: . Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? In your example there are two subClientEntities and they are dictionaries, not lists. Do you want to print the elements and their corresponding values in the dictionary?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer was missing, I am citing here the answer of Vladimir Botka, which really helped me a lot:

code:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ scriptVal.matches|map(attribute='subClientEntity')|list }}"
```

result:

```
 ok: [localhost] => (item={'appName': 'Virtual Server', 'backupsetName': 'backupset-test', 'clientName': 'Name-vcagent', 'displayName': 'Name-VCAgent', 'instanceName': 'VC01', 'subclientName': 'test'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "appName": "Virtual Server",
        "backupsetName": "backupset-test",
        "clientName": "Name-vcagent",
        "displayName": "Name-VCAgent",
        "instanceName": "VC01",
        "subclientName": "test"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'appName': 'Virtual Server', 'backupsetName': 'Test01', 'clientName': 'Name-vcagent', 'displayName': 'Name-VCAgent', 'instanceName': 'VC01', 'subclientName': 'start9pm'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "appName": "Virtual Server",
        "backupsetName": "Test01",
        "clientName": "Name-vcagent",
        "displayName": "Name-VCAgent",
        "instanceName": "VC01",
        "subclientName": "start9pm"
    }
}
```

code:

```
      - debug:
          msg: "{{ scriptVal.matches.0.subClientEntity.keys()|list }}" '''
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "appName",
        "backupsetName",
        "clientName",
        "displayName",
        "instanceName",
        "subclientName"
    ]
}
```

code:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.1 }}: {{ item.0[item.1] }}"
    with_nested:
      - "{{ scriptVal.matches|map(attribute='subClientEntity')|list }}"
      - "{{ scriptVal.matches.0.subClientEntity.keys()|list }}"
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'appName': 'Virtual Server', 'backupsetName': 'backupset-test', 'clientName': 'Name-vcagent', 'displayName': 'Name-VCAgent', 'instanceName': 'VC01', 'subclientName': 'test'}, 'appName']) => {
    "msg": "appName: Virtual Server"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'appName': 'Virtual Server', 'backupsetName': 'backupset-test', 'clientName': 'Name-vcagent', 'displayName': 'Name-VCAgent', 'instanceName': 'VC01', 'subclientName': 'test'}, 'backupsetName']) => {
    "msg": "backupsetName: backupset-test"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'appName': 'Virtual Server', 'backupsetName': 'backupset-test', 'clientName': 'Name-vcagent', 'displayName': 'Name-VCAgent', 'instanceName': 'VC01', 'subclientName': 'test'}, 'clientName']) => {
    "msg": "clientName: Name-vcagent"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'appName': 'Virtual Server', 'backupsetName': 'backupset-test', 'clientName': 'Name-vcagent', 'displayName': 'Name-VCAgent', 'instanceName': 'VC01', 'subclientName': 'test'}, 'displayName']) => {
    "msg": "displayName: Name-VCAgent"
}
```